# Can I merge a corporate team SO account with my personal SO account?

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, merge-accounts, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have a corporate-based, "Private Team, Business" (that's what the screen says below the team logo that sits just under the SO logo in the top left) team account, registered and used with a personal private email address... let's say unit@example.com.

I have an old SO account, this one I'm using for this post: @monsto.

Currently, if i get an summary email for the @unit account and click the link in the email, first it says:
[image]

And after clicking the "Add" button, then it says:
[image]

The goal is to have set so that I don't have these messages AND to not have to logout/in for the different views.

How can I clear out this error message?

Comment: I made the mistake of using the M word in the body of the original text, so I edited the message to focus on the crux of the problem which is the error message.

Comment: You can fix the error message by merging your accounts.  Why did you edit it?

Comment: If you have two separate accounts and you want them to be one account, merging is the solution. If you have two separate accounts and you want them to stay two separate accounts, you need to use a different email address on the @monsto one or the `@unit` one. If you really want to not have to log in/out between your two accounts (assuming you don't want to just have them open in two browsers) you'll have to merge - so.... Can you edit to explain why the linked question isn't sufficient?